# Adding a for loop to a working web scraper (Python and Beautifulsoup)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have query regarding for loops and adding one to an already working web scraper to run through a list of webpages. What I'm looking at it probably two or three simple lines of code.

I appreciate this has probably been asked many times before and answered but I've been struggling to get some code to work for me for quite some time now. I'm relatively new to Python and looking to improve.

**Background info:**

I've written a web scraper using Python and Beautifulsoup which is successfully able to take a webpage from TransferMarkt.com and scrape all the required web links. The script is made up of two parts:

1. In the first part, I am taking the webpage for a football league,
   e.g. The Premier League, and extract the webpage links for all the
   individual teams in the league table and put them in a list.
2. In the second part of my script, I then take this list of individual teams and further extract information of each of the individual players for each team and then join this together to form one big pandas DataFrame of player information.

My query is regarding how to add a for loop to the first part of this web scraper to not just extract the team links from one league webpage, but to extract links from a list of league webpages.

Below I've included an example of a football league webpage, my web scraper code, and the output.

**Example:**

Example webpage to scrape (Premier League - code GB1): https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/jumplist/startseite/wettbewerb/gb1/plus/?saison_id=2019

**Code (part 1 of 2) - scrape individual team links from league webpage:**

```
# Python libraries

##  Data Preprocessing
import pandas as pd

##  Data scraping libraries
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


# Assign league by code, e.g. Premier League = 'GB1', to the list_league_selected variable
list_league_selected = 'GB1'


# Assign season by year to season variable e.g. 2014/15 season = 2014
season = '2019'


# Create an empty list to assign these values to
team_links = []


# Web scraper script

## Process League Table
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36'}
page = 'https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/jumplist/startseite/wettbewerb/' + id + '/plus/?saison_id=' + season
tree = requests.get(page, headers = headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(tree.content, 'html.parser')

## Create an empty list to assign these values to - team_links
team_links = []

## Extract all links with the correct CSS selector
links = soup.select("a.vereinprofil_tooltip")

## We need the location that the link is pointing to, so for each link, take the link location. 
## Additionally, we only need the links in locations 1, 3, 5, etc. of our list, so loop through those only
for i in range(1,59,3):
    team_links.append(links[i].get("href"))

## For each location that we have taken, add the website before it - this allows us to call it later
for i in range(len(team_links)):
    team_links[i] = "https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk" + team_links[i]


# View list of team weblinks assigned to variable - team_links
team_links
```

**Output:**
Extracted links from example webpage (20 links in total for example webpage, just showing 4):

```
team_links = ['https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/manchester-city/startseite/verein/281/saison_id/2019',
 'https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/fc-liverpool/startseite/verein/31/saison_id/2019',
 'https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/tottenham-hotspur/startseite/verein/148/saison_id/2019',
 'https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/fc-chelsea/startseite/verein/631/saison_id/2019',
...,
'https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/sheffield-united/startseite/verein/350/saison_id/2019']
```

Using this list of teams - `team_links`, I am then able to further extract information for all the players of each team with the following code. From this output I'm then able to create a pandas DataFrame of all players info:

**Code (part 2 of 2) - scrape individual player information using the team_links list:**

```
# Create an empty DataFrame for the data, df
df = pd.DataFrame()

# Run the scraper through each of the links in the team_links list
for i in range(len(team_links)):

    # Download and process the team page
    page = team_links[i]
    df_headers = ['position_number' , 'position_description' , 'name' , 'dob' , 'nationality' , 'value']
    pageTree = requests.get(page, headers = headers)
    pageSoup = BeautifulSoup(pageTree.content, 'lxml')

    # Extract all data
    position_number = [item.text for item in pageSoup.select('.items .rn_nummer')]
    position_description = [item.text for item in pageSoup.select('.items td:not([class])')]
    name = [item.text for item in pageSoup.select('.hide-for-small .spielprofil_tooltip')]
    dob = [item.text for item in pageSoup.select('.zentriert:nth-of-type(4):not([id])')]
    nationality = ['/'.join([i['title'] for i in item.select('[title]')]) for item in pageSoup.select('.zentriert:nth-of-type(5):not([id])')]
    value = [item.text for item in pageSoup.select('.rechts.hauptlink')]
    df_temp = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(position_number, position_description, name, dob, nationality, value)), columns = df_headers)
    df = df.append(df_temp)   # This last line of code is mine. It appends to temporary data to the master DataFrame, df

# View the pandas DataFrame
df
```

**My question to you - adding a for loop to go through all the leagues:**

What I need to do is replace the `list_league_selected` variable assigned to an individual league code in the first part of my code, and instead use a for loop to go through the full list of league codes - `list_all_leagues`. This list of league codes is as follows:

```
list_all_leagues = ['L1', 'GB1', 'IT1', 'FR1', 'ES1']    # codes for the top 5 European leagues
```

I've read through several solutions but I'm struggling to get the loop to work and append the full list of team webpages at the correct part. I believe I'm now really close to completing my scraper and any advice on how to create this for loop would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: There is a ton of information here, is there no way to condense things? I'm not sure I understand what specifically you're struggling with, either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually I've taken time to clear much mistakes in your code. and shorten the big road. Below you can achieve your target.

> I considered been under antibiotic protection () meant under `requests.Session()` to maintain the `Session` during my loop, which means to prevent `TCP` layer security from `blocking/refusing/dropping` my `packet/request` while `Scraping`.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0'
}

leagues = ['L1', 'GB1', 'IT1', 'FR1', 'ES1']


def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        links = []
        for lea in leagues:
            print(f"Fetching Links from {lea}")
            r = req.get(url.format(lea), headers=headers)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
            link = [f"{url[:31]}{item.next_element.get('href')}" for item in soup.findAll(
                "td", class_="hauptlink no-border-links hide-for-small hide-for-pad")]
            links.extend(link)

        print(f"Collected {len(links)} Links")
        goals = []
        for num, link in enumerate(links):
            print(f"Extracting Page# {num +1}")
            r = req.get(link, headers=headers)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
            target = soup.find("table", class_="items")
            pn = [pn.text for pn in target.select("div.rn_nummer")]
            pos = [pos.text for pos in target.findAll("td", class_=False)]
            name = [name.text for name in target.select("td.hide")]
            dob = [date.find_next(
                "td").text for date in target.select("td.hide")]
            nat = [" / ".join([a.get("alt") for a in nat.find_all_next("td")[1] if a.get("alt")]) for nat in target.findAll(
                "td", itemprop="athlete")]
            val = [val.get_text(strip=True)
                   for val in target.select('td.rechts.hauptlink')]
            goal = zip(pn, pos, name, dob, nat, val)
            df = pd.DataFrame(goal, columns=[
                              'position_number', 'position_description', 'name', 'dob', 'nationality', 'value'])
            goals.append(df)

        new = pd.concat(goals)
        new.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)


main("https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/jumplist/startseite/wettbewerb/{}/plus/?saison_id=2019")
```

Output: [View Online](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/19d890dee4dc675f2d3321194f8c3b1c/data.csv)

[image]

Comment: Really great Ahmed, this is exactly what I was looking for! I'm still learning about webscraping and best ways to do it.

Thank you very much for taking the time to answer my question and rewrite the script!

Comment: @EddWebster you welcome :) glad to help. you can up-vote if you liked as well

Comment: Apologies, yeah I tried to do that but StackOverflow gives me the following message as a pop up box:

"Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

I might see if i can give you an upvote some other way with another acocunt because your answer deserves the credit! Thanks very much!